# Are Vault policies hierarchical?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

When authorizing access to a path do I have to enable read access to all parent folders? I couldn't find such a statement in the docs but a few tests confirm this. Consider this:

```
path "secret/myapp/*" {
   capabilities = ["create", "read", "sudo", "update", "list", "delete"]
}
```

With the proper role assigned I cannot read `secret/myapp/test`. I need to at least add this to the role:

```
path "secret/*" {
   capabilities = ["read"]
}
```

This seems to contradict the docs which say that the most specific rule matches.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I am not crazy. It turns out the KV backend requires you to change the path like described here: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kv/kv-v2.html

I was able to fix my problem by changing the policy to:

```
path "secret/data/myapp/*" {
 capabilities = ["create", "read", "sudo", "update", "list", "delete"]
}
```

Just sneak a `/data` before `myapp`. What's more the "fix" I attempted (giving access to the parent path) works by sheer accident: this way I was giving access to the `secret/data` which is more than enough.